# MySQL, join many to many relationship query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        `persons`.`name`,
        '[START_Name_END]',
        `persons`.`id`,
        '[START_Id_END]',
        `persons`.`isteacher`,
        '[START_IsTeacher_END]'
    SEPARATOR '[START_ROWSEPERATOR_END]') AS persons_values,
    `locations`.`name` AS locations_name,
    `locations`.`id` AS locations_id
FROM `locations`
INNER JOIN `locations_persons` ON `locations_persons`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`
INNER JOIN `persons` ON `persons`.`id` = `locations_persons`.`person_id`  
GROUP BY `locations`.`id`
ORDER BY `locations`.`id`
```

The reason why I use `GROUP_CONCAT` is to get all rows from `persons` table, that have reference in the association table, in the same column

I use  `[START_Name_END], [START_Id_END]` to split the result later in my code and `[START_ROWSEPERATOR_END]` to determine if it's same row or a new one.

Everything works just fine so far.

The thing is if any row in `locations` table has no reference to any row in `persons` table, I'm NOT getting that row in the results!

I beleive that the problem is in `JOIN`, what should I use to fetch all rows regardless if that row has reference in the association table or not?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add some line breaks to your query

Comment: Your code is unreadable.  Please format properly.  Probably try `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I did, Hopefully it's more readable now!
Jeff's solution worked but I'm just wondering if it could cause any issue in another scenario

Comment: With left joins `persons_values` will be `NULL` if the location has no related persons. Just keep that in mind, when you try to parse it.

Comment: I tried LEFT JOIN, it returns only rows that they have references on the right side. But with Jeff's solution "LEFT OUTER JOIN" it worked fine!
Thank you guys for participating!
Special thanks to Paul for editing my code. I'm new and don't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations_persons` ...
```

-- Edit

Sorry, I'm new at answering these StackOverflow things and didn't give this the attention that it deserves before responding.

Your table structure is a classic many-to-many join, so if there is no person for a given location, then there would only be location data in the locations table.  As such, you would need to have a LEFT OUTER JOIN for both the join on locations_persons AND the join from locations_persons to persons.

If you're still having troubles I'll create a quick MySQL database and test things out.. I'll do that from now on, but thought I should reply more fully now because of my bad partial answer earlier.

--Edit2

Regarding expecting issues:  When you left outer join, any join that fails (i.e. there's rows on the left side, but no match on the right side) will have the tables from the right returning all null values.  In this case, you would want your query to properly handle all fields in `locations_persons` and `persons` returning null values.

If GROUP_CONCAT doesn't deal with this well (I'm not familiar with it), you might need to wrap these persons.* fields in an IFNULL, if you're having problems:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT `persons`.`name`,
    '[START_Name_END]',
    IFNULL(`persons`.`id`, ''),
    '[START_Id_END]',
    IFNULL(`persons`.`isteacher`, ''),
    '[START_IsTeacher_END]' SEPARATOR '[START_ROWSEPERATOR_END]'
  ) AS persons_values,
  `locations`.`name` AS locations_name,
  `locations`.`id` AS locations_id
FROM
  `locations`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations_persons` ON
    `locations_persons`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `persons` ON
    `persons`.`id` = `locations_persons`.`person_id`
GROUP BY
  `locations`.`id`
ORDER BY
  `locations`.`id`
```

Comment: Unfortunately same problem!

Comment: You're using two INNER JOINs, is it possible that a missing entry from PERSONS is also suppressing things?  Does using a LEFT OUTER JOIN on both of your joins fix things up?

If not, could you post some table definitions and INSERTS with sample data, along with your expected results?

You have no WHERE clause here, so the joins are the only possible place where data could be getting dropped.  LEFT OUTER JOIN will include all rows from the left side of the join, and use NULL values for the fields from the missing right side.

Comment: Thank you Jeff! It does!
My quetion now is, would LEFT OUTER JOIN cause any issues?

Comment: Thank you Jeff!, it's crystal clear!
Actually what I needed was that JOIN returns NULL if there is no rows on the right side which it does now after I changed to LEFT OUTER JOIN.
Thanks again! :)